# I can't start wampserver (0x000007b)

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I get the error message: 
`wampserver cant start correctly  (0x000007b).`

Initially, wampserver was working well on my pc. Then, I had to delete some folders. I was prompted by windows that a system file was part of the files I was deleting and if I continue, a program might not work properly.

I ignored this because the folders I was deleting were on my desktop, but not directly in drive C.

After this, wamserver stopped working.
I uninstalled it and installed it again, and then I was prompted of some missing files (MSVCP120.dll and MSVCR120.dll).

I downloaded and pasted them in my drive c path :// drive c / windows / sysWOW64 /

I wasn't prompted of missing files anymore, but rather had this message anytime I start wamp:
`wampserver cannot start correctly (0x000007b)`

I checked and my windows is up to date and am using Direct X 12. I also have the latest .NetFrame work. Please what can I do? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing wamp after adding the DLLs?

Comment: yes I did @Emmanuel. during the initial install, I was prompted that those files are missing and that WampServer wont work. and after installing them, that error message stopped coming but rather had this error (0x000007b)

Comment: It might be a mistake, but I think you should put the files also in C:\Windows\System32

Comment: _I downloaded and pasted them in my drive c path_ THAT IS NOT the way to install te MSVC Runtime libraries. They must be installed properly. See [the bottom of the WAMPServer backup repo page](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/) and download the "All VC Redistribuable Packages (x86_x64) (32 & 64bits)" and install them ALL one by one in logical version number order. If they are already installed pick the REPAIR option to make sure you didn't do any damage to them with your delete or copy

Comment: thank you everyone. I realized the error was from the file I download from the DLL website. I had an initial backup of the same needed files and after placing them in the system folder, the error stopped and WampServer is working correctly now. thank you all. will keep your advice too @RiggsFolly. thanks.